# Why when i changed index file or other file, it isn't re-render?

Tags: angular, docker-compose, dockerfile

i'm beginner learn docker. I follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2UkQ2CND68. It's successfully but when i changed index file. It isn't re-rendered?

i try create docker-compose file but It isn't also  re-rendered.

dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.2.0

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install && npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9

# add app
COPY /front-end /usr/src/app

#RUN pwd && ls

CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  angular:
    container_name: bench_angular
#    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/angular/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /front-end:/app
    ports:
    - 4200:4200
    networks:
    - bench
networks:
  bench:
    driver: bridge
```

I expect it re-render when i change content of one file

Comment: @malbarmawi it not work

Comment: first run docker-compose build then run docker-compose up. build command will update the image

Comment: i add --poll 200 in dockerfile. It works.